# django-haystack with elastic search not building index for newly created objects

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

using

```
Django==1.8
django-haystack==2.3.1
```

setting.py:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE':'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
        'TIMEOUT': 60,
    },
}
```

Newly created(updated or deleted )objects are not updating in my elastic search index.
entering `.manage.py rebuild_index` command each time when creating or updating objects which working perfectly and updating each change.

Is there any solution to auto rebuild index when changes made to model objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the real time signal processor activated in settings:

```
HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'haystack.signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor'
```